# Google App Engine: versioning with custom sub domains

Tags: google-app-engine, subdomain

I'm trying to setup GAE with a custom sub domain and a specific version url.

For example I have an app running with the following setup

```
VERSION_ID: 1234
SERVICE_ID: my-app
PROJECT_ID: my-project
```

The provided url `https://1234-dot-my-app-dot-my-project.ew.r.appspot.com` works fine. But I can't get to work with my custom domain + sub domain. Googles documentation states the following urls are the same:

```
https://VERSION_ID-dot-default-dot-PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com
https://VERSION_ID.CUSTOM_DOMAIN
```

But when visiting `1234.api.mycustomdomain.com` it does not work. However `api.mycustomdomain.com` works, pointing to the latest running version of `my-app`

What am I missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#example_urls), routing by using an specific `VERSION_ID` it will only work for the default service. As the example shows:

> **default service**
>
> https://VERSION_ID-dot-default-dot-PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com
> https://VERSION_ID.CUSTOM_DOMAIN

And in your case you are targeting the service `SERVICE_ID: my-app` and thus why the routing is not working. So in your case you need to use the following:

`https://SERVICE_ID.CUSTOM_DOMAIN` which in your case equals to:

`https://my-app.CUSTOM_DOMAIN`

Comment: So there's no way around this apart from using the default service... Also how should my custom domains be setup? Do I need to do anything in the dispatch file?

Comment: Well now there's the possibility to add GAE as the backend of a Load Balancer, with the recent release of [Serverless Network Endpoint Groups](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts) so you can do the routing like this. As for the domains setup, the routing is done using the URL but you can also use a dispatch.yaml if you want to override the default URL routing, but still it won't work with specific versioning.

Comment: ok thanks I think I'll just make my service the default one for now !